# FFMPEG shift chroma plane horizontally

Tags: video, ffmpeg, yuv

I'm trying to process the video I recorded from my capture card and that involves storing the videoframes as PNG images at some point. The problem is, FFmpeg shifts the chroma planes ~2px to the right when converting from YUV to RGB. This adds to the already existing shift that my capture card introduces and becomes quite noticeable. I tried the sws_flags solution but it only fixes the blockiness. I also tried to horizontally flip the video before conversion in hopes that it would reverse the shift direction, to no effect.

So I need to compensate for both and shift chroma to the left. I've seen examples of overlay filter_complex usage [shifting the whole video](https://superuser.com/questions/727375/how-to-offset-a-video-horizontally-in-ffmpeg), as well as the [chroma planes extraction](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FancyFilteringExamples) via lut_yuv, but I can't figure out how to shift only the chroma plane. There doesn't seem to be a "chroma" mode in the blend filter either, which would have allowed me to replace chroma with its modified version.

Conversion log:

```
F:\records>ffmpeg64 -i src.avi -ss 4.5 -vframes 1 -f image2 -vcodec png -sws_fl
ags accurate_rnd+full_chroma_int test.png
ffmpeg version N-89073-gff8f40a630 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers

  built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --e
nable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libblur
ay --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopu
s --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --ena
ble-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-lib
x264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-z
lib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-cuda --enable-c
uvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-l
ibmfx
  libavutil      56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
  libavcodec     58.  3.102 / 58.  3.102
  libavformat    58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
  libavdevice    58.  0.100 / 58.  0.100
  libavfilter     7.  0.101 /  7.  0.101
  libswscale      5.  0.101 /  5.  0.101
  libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101
  libpostproc    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
[avi @ 0000000000420180] non-interleaved AVI
Input #0, avi, from 'src.avi':
  Duration: 00:02:18.23, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 881232 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 1280x720, 881325
kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 60 tbn, 60 tbc
File 'test.png' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> png (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, image2, to 'test.png':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.2.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgb24, 1280x720, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbn,
60 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.3.102 png
frame=    1 fps=0.7 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.01 bitrate=N/A speed=0.0115x

video:274kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing o
verhead: unknown
```

Source image: [image: https://i.imgur.com/IShYK77.png]

You can see there's already a 2px shift just from the YUY2 capture format

FFMpeg conversion: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnG7H.png]

Now it's twice as big

Comment: Can you show before and after images? Also, the YUV->RGB command conversion and its log.

Comment: Edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic method to adjust or shift chroma is to use the `geq` filter.

```
ffmpeg64 -i src.avi -filter_complex 
   "format=yuv444p,extractplanes=y+u+v[y][u][v];
     [u]geq=lum='p(X+1,Y)'[u];[v]geq=lum='p(X+1,Y)'[v];
     [y][u][v]mergeplanes=0x001020:yuv444p" 
 -ss 4.5 -vframes 1 -f image2 -vcodec png -sws_flags accurate_rnd+full_chroma_int test.png
```

The chroma is upscaled to full size, then the individual planes are extracted. In the `geq` filters, applied to the U and V extracted planes, the value of each pixel is taken from the pixel to its right. This will lose the original values of the leftmost column of pixels. Finally, the original luma and processed chroma planes are merged. Using some trial and error, you should be able to get the offsets right.