# Keep equirectangular side-data when using video filter on 360 Video in ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, metadata, virtual-reality

I have a 360° Video and want to shift it sideways using ffmpeg so that the default viewpoint when opening the video in a player is shifted. I found this question ([How to offset a video horizontally in ffmpeg?](https://superuser.com/questions/727375/how-to-offset-a-video-horizontally-in-ffmpeg)) that helped me getting the shifting done, but when I use this approach to shift the video the side-data of the video (containing the information that it is in equirectangular format) is gone.

This is the relevant part from using `ffprobe` on my input file:

`Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 00:00:05.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 57592 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc), 3840x1920 [SAR 1:1 DAR 2:1], 57515 kb/s, 29.95 fps, 29.95 tbr, 29948 tbn, 59.90 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Side data:
      spherical: equirectangular (0.000000/0.000000/0.000000)`

Then I use the overlay filter as described in the link above like this:

`ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][0:v]overlay=960:0[bg]; [bg][0:v]overlay=960-W,format=yuvj420p[out]" -map "[out]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -c:a copy test_shifted.mp4`

An the resulting file does not have the equirectangular side data in it:

`Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test_shifted.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 00:00:05.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 245636 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc), 3840x1920 [SAR 1:1 DAR 2:1], 245758 kb/s, 29.95 fps, 29.95 tbr, 14974 tbn, 59.90 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler`

I looked into this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44760588/preserving-side-data-information-for-360-video-transcoding-using-ffmpeg) and tried the approaches mentioned there (`keepside` flag, `-strict unofficial`) but the question itself deals with stream copying and none of it seems to work when using the filter on the video stream.

I am using `ffmpeg version 3.4.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1`. If anyone can help me keep my metadata that would be much appreciated!

Comment: did you ever find a solution here?  I'm running into the same problem when just concatenating files

Comment: I did not find a direct solution, but a workaround using (if I remember correctly) the [spatial media metadata injector software](https://github.com/google/spatial-media/releases). So I first applied the processing with ffmpeg and then re-added the spatial metadata.